# Symfony Twig Call Continer

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 3 with Twig.

In every route I need to make a call to entity:

```
$posts = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('AppBundle:Posts')
->findAll();
```

There is a way that I can do this globally?
And call it from the twig instead of in the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a service that will do it and inject it as a twig global

```
#app/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        posts_service: '@app_posts_service'
```

Then define the service

```
#app/services.yml
services:
    app_posts_service:
        class: AppBundle\Service\PostsService
        arguments: ["@doctrine"]
```

Make sure your services file is getting imported into your config:

```
#app/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

Then define the service:

```
// src/AppBundle/Service/PostsService.php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

class PostsService
{
    protected $doctrine;
    public function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function getAllPosts()
    {
        return $this->doctrine
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Posts')
            ->findAll();
    }
}
```

Then use it in any twig file like:

```
{%for post in posts_service.getAllPosts() %}
    {{ post.title }} {# or whatever #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks! when i add the line to config.yml i'm getting: The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "app_posts_service".

Comment: wroks! great thatnks

Comment: can you send me pm?

Comment: @kalites is your `app/services.yml` included in your `app/config.yml`?

Comment: @kalites If this solved your problem it would be nice if you would accept the answer. Thanks and good luck!